# Misunderstanding of scopes in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Why am I getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: preload is not a function` in the following code?

```
preload = (event, ui) ->
  preload = new createjs.LoadQueue()
  preload.loadFile('/images/medium/missing.png')
  return

$('.tool').draggable(
  {
    revert: true
    drag: (event, ui) ->
      preload(event, ui)
  })
```

I thoungt I alredy defined `preload()`. The function executes anyway despite the error. Where is the catch?

Comment: Have you tried just passing `preload` as the value of the `drag` property instead of creating the anonymous function to call it? Like `drag: preload`.

Comment: Compiled code seems good to me and runs just fine.

Comment: @reda yes, in that case I get `ReferenceError: e is not defined` and the whole app crashes.

Comment: I think Reda is suggesting just `drag: preload`, not `drag: preload(e, ui)`.

Comment: My bad. Now it works fine. But still, can somebody explaing to me why the first example is a bad practice?

Comment: Also note that the `drag` event triggers multiple times while the dragging is happening every time the mouse moves. For preloading stuff you probably want the `start` event instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That was just an example of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your original question

In most languages with closures (including JavaScript) the inner **preload** and the outer **preload** could and would be separate. CoffeeScript though does not allow Shadowing or defining a same variable in a deeper scope And doing it will overwrite the global one. Read [This article](https://donatstudios.com/CoffeeScript-Madness) for more info on coffeescript scoping.